# ActionScript / AIR - MouseEvent Limitations on Touch Enabled Devices?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, touch, mouseevent

If mouse events are used instead of touch events on touch enabled devices, does that limit "touch" input to one touch at a time?

If a mouse down event is currently in progress, will a following mouse down event simply not register or cancel the previous?

How are mouse events, historically used as single control pointers on desktop systems, handled on touch enabled devices capable of several simultaneous touch points?

Event classes have a `clone()` function typically used to fire multiple events, so I'm assuming MouseEvent is not limited.  However, my goal is to actually limit my application to one touch at a time (exclusive touch), but I'm not sure if this will be automatically handled with the use of mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse events are handled in the same manner on both single-touch and multi-touch devices. If you only want single-touch, use the MouseEvent events and if you want multi-touch use the TouchEvent events. You can use the Multitouch.supportsTouchEvents property to determine touch support.

Comment: do you know what happens when another mouse event is called while one is currently in progress?  say i'm dragging a display object with MOUSE_MOVE and i suddenly MOUSE_DOWN on another part of the stage.  does MOUSE_MOVE become interrupted or is the new MOUSE_DOWN ignored?